# In vim, the cursor jumps around and extra characters are displayed until the line wraps

Tags: vim, markdown

When I'm using vim, in a file with a *.md file extension, the cursor jumps back and forth as I'm typing, and extra characters are displayed. This makes it difficult to see what I'm typing. But when the line wraps, the line redraws and looks normal.

Vim 7.4

I'm seeing this while using vim on cloud9. Not sure if that matters? This only happens in *.md files.

[Before the line wraps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N53uK.png)

[After the line wraps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFaOr.png)

Comment: Does it happen with other filetypes? Does it happen without any setup `$ vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: In all of my files, the cursor will occasionally jump around a little bit, but markdown files are the worst. I hadn't tried vim `vim -Nu NONE`, that's new to me. I tried it and the problem went away. So I'm guessing it's something in my `.vimrc` file then?

Comment: In your vimrc or in your plugins.